# jsp send file through post request

Tags: jsp, post, file-upload

I am trying to make a JSP page that acts as an HTTP client of another website via a POST message. Thus, I want, from a JSP page, to set up a POST request to another site and process the results, analogously to the PHP 'curl' function. How can I do this?

Comment: See commons.apache.org/fileupload/.

Comment: don't know if fileupload is the write thing here, is more a request, I need to make a POST request (curl in PHP) to a server, and the POST should contain a file.

Comment: Then you should edit your post to state clearly and completely what you want. As it is, your question is likely to be closed as unclear. I'll take a shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't do this in JSP. Write a Java class to do this work, test the java class, and then use it from your JSP page. Putting code of this complexity into a JSP page is a recipe for an unmaintainable, undebuggable nightmare.
2. Whether you code this in the JSP page or elsewhere, it's java code. If you want to do a POST to an HTTP server from Java, one good solution is the Apache Commons HTTP Client. The web site for that has plenty of documentation, including examples, of how to set up a POST, sent it, and read the response.

Comment: could not find anything useful there, isn't there a java class to do this? with an example maybe? is it so difficult to do this in jsp?

Comment: Dunno. you could search for 'taglib' and 'http' and see what pops out.